# Interaction between continous variables

Tags: interpretation

I have a question regarding the interpretation of a interaction term between two continous variables that are temperature and time. I did not center these two variable and I inserted directly the interaction term. I obtained a negative coefficient of -0.003194.What is the interpretation of this coefficient? I'm confused.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste in the other coefficients? What is your response variable?

Answer (score 0):

The response variable is BMI. I obtained a coefficient for variable time of 0.02214 and for temperature of 0.003194.The interaction coefficient of them is -0.00003.I did not understand an other point: why when i did not consider the interaction term I obtained a negative coefficient for time and then it becomes positive? That it was more reasonable since I expect a decrease of BMI during the time.